# mysql SELECT LIKE must match whole words only to the variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a $string variable, and I use

```
 SELECT * FROM db WHERE description LIKE '%$string%' OR headline LIKE '%$string%'
```

As seen, I want to search the two fields "description" and "headline" to see if the string variable matches any of them.

Problem is that I want it to match whole words!!!

Ex: If description contains "hello", It is enough if $string is an 'h'. this is not what I want.It has to match the whole word only!

I split the querystring into words for this? or what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want full word matching you should consider trying FULLTEXT searching.  One prerequisite is that your table must be using the MyISAM engine:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  headline VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  FULLTEXT(headline, description)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

You would query for matches like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE MATCH (headline,description) AGAINST('$string');
```

This has the added benefit of ordering your results by relevancy.

Comment: why isnt there a feature like this on InnoDb databases?

Comment: @Jimmery there will be FULLTEXT searching in MySQL 5.6 InnoDB when it's released. Keep an eye out for it!

Comment: Note that full text search won't work on short words (<4 characters) or phrases with spaces

Answer (score 13):

An alternative to full text searching, which may be sufficient, is to use a REGEXP function.

Your example query might then be:

```
SELECT *
  FROM db
 WHERE description REGEXP '[[:<:]]$string[[:>:]]' = 1
    OR headline REGEXP '[[:<:]]$string[[:>:]]' = 1
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Note that `REGEXP` is pretty inefficient for larger sets of data because MySQL can't take advantage of indexing.

Comment: To clarify, it can't take advantage of indexing for `LIKE '%term%'` either which is what the OP already had.  However it *could* with `MATCH() ... AGAINST()` if there's a FULLTEXT index.